# Image binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have an Image control that is supposed to do a slide show.
Here are the binding I used to achieve this:

```
    Binding mapBinding = new Binding();
    mapBinding.Source = slideView;
    mapBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("ImageDrawing");
    sliderImage.SetBinding(System.Windows.Controls.Image.SourceProperty, mapBinding);
```

And a class `SlideImage`

```
public class SlideImage : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public ImageSource ImageDrawing{get;set;} 
    public void ChangeImage(){
         // Load another image
         // Update ImageDrawing
         // Fire property changed event
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

I found many examples on the net using the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to listen for data source changes. The only problem is the `Image` control does not have that property.

How do I hook up my `sliderImage` control to update on `SlideImage.PropertyChanged`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably will update automatically, if you're actually calling `PropertyChanged` when calling the setter of `ImageDrawing`.

You aren't firing `PropertyChanged` for your `ImageDrawing` property in the code you've provided.  Try this:

```
private ImageSource imageDrawing;
public ImageSource ImageDrawing
{
    get { return imageDrawing; }
    set
    {
        imageDrawing = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("ImageDrawing");
    }
}

private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if(PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Just checked my code, I am actually firing the event from the model but the view consumed it and did not forward it to the GUI. Thanks a lot for the pointer, I appreciate +1